# Do Legendary skins ever go on sale?

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legends, you can buy skins to supplement your champions to make them look awesome. A category for these skins include one called legendary skins. These skins rework how the champion works, how their skill animation looks and their voice overs. But they cost 1820 riot points (which is really expensive).

Every week, about 3 skins go on sale for 50% their normal price. I was wondering if the legendary skins ever go on sale. As far as I know, I have never seen one go on sale. But of course I don't check 100% of the time.

I mean come on look at these skins... :3

[image]

Comment: My girlfriend has both of those...and super teemo...and like every teemo skin.

Comment: @Emerica apparently your girlfriend has good taste, because Teemo is obviously the coolest thing since sliced bread. ^_^

Comment: @Ender Never underestimate the power of the scouts code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Legendary Skins will never go on sale, and have not done so in the past. While I can't find the original official statement at the moment, the forums reassert this every few days when someone asks.

It is part of their essence in addition to their exorbitant prices. They're meant for people who are willing to fork over that much just to see their little adorable Void creature spew pretty fireworks.

Comment: There also no longer making them as they don't make enough money on them they will only make 975 RP skins now (Was part of a statement from Riot)

Comment: Fiddle Skin anniversary was **NOT** on sale, but it have a price BELOW the normal Legendary price (only 975RP)

Comment: I'm not sure if the above answer is true still. I currently see an on sale skin in the shop right now (one of the spirit blossom ones). You also can get Legendary skins in your shop when events come around.